# Javascript Function instance is automatically casted to object and can't be called anymore

Tags: javascript, function, object, casting, anonymous-function

I'm working with a fairly complex Javascript program wich, at a given point, returns some nested anonymous functions.

Sometimes, when I try to "apply" one of such anonymous functions ("f" in this example)...

```
f.apply (this.context, args)
```

...I get an "f.apply is not a function" error.

It's weird, because alert(f) displays the function source code but typeof(f) returns "object" (not "function").

```
alert (f) --> displays "function (input) { self.checkToken (input, regex, callback) }"
```

Also, f.call and f.apply are undefined.

Checking the typeof(f) at some stages of execution always returns "function". I can't explain why, when I need to call the function, it casts to object.

I've tested the code against Firefox and Microsoft JScript engine, obtaining the same results.

Maybe I'm missing some basic aspect of Javascript anonymous blocks? :-\

Comment: You should post some of the code involved.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be better to post some code, but then I realized that maybe reading 2.5k lines of code is a lot more that I can ask to you :)

I'll try to reproduce the error and paste a little snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! Mea culpa...

I realized I was returning the function inside an array of length 1, so "alert()" showed the first object's toString representation.

Mystery resolved and public shame on me :)